# Execute a SPARQL query in SWI-Prolog, on a OWL ontology

Tags: sparql, swi-prolog, semantics, semantic-web, ontology

I'd like to know how to execute a SPARQL query in SWI-Prolog, after I've loaded an ontology from a OWL/RDF file.

I've found that it's possible to execute a query through sparql_query/3, but it require a server.

Answer (score 1):

You could dig into the code of [ClioPatria](http://e-culture.multimedian.nl/software/ClioPatria.shtml), which is a Semantic Web server written in Prolog. I'm sure there is code for loading an RDF/XML file and querying the graph using SPARQL without actually running the server.

Running an easy-to-use SPARQL server like [Fuseki](http://incubator.apache.org/jena/documentation/serving_data/) and do data adding and querying via SPARQL(U) or command line is probably easier though.